# Is it correct to use "were not they ...?" to ask question about some people in negative way?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, alternatives

> **Were not they** interested in my profile? 
> **Were not they** from London?

Both questions are negative and want to know about some people's information/ideas. If it's not something native people would use, what's the equivalent and alternative?

Comment: It is correct, but you have got 'not' in the wrong place. Were they not interested in my profile? Were they not from London? Was he not able to drive the car? Are you not an accountant?

Comment: You have 'not' in the correct place if you use the common contraction: Weren't they interested in my profile?
              Weren't they from London?

Comment: @BruceMurray Is there any difference between "weren't" and "Were not"?

Comment: None, they mean the same thing, but the non-contracted form (were not) cannot be used to begin a question, as I have indicated.

Comment: Other examples of this issue:  Will not you be taking a vacation this year? .......WRONG!.............the correct way to say this = Won't you be taking a vacation this year?

Comment: @BruceMurray Thank you so much, I guess you can provide these information as an answer, so more people might find it helpful by finding in by Google Search

Comment: My wife is from Lancashire, and if I say "I won't be seeing Jim this week", she will say "Will you not?". I have, over 30 years, adopted this form.

Comment: @Michael Will you not? is fine;  will not you? is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just an example of non standard form in widespread use.

Comment: Constructions like _were not they?_ were used in the past, but for some reason, if not using a contraction, today we always use _were they not?_